# SelectedIndex is throwing error for WpfCombobox having large no of listitems

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

We are testing a WPF application with CodedUi using C#. In our application we have a combobox with large number of list items (16 list items) in it. The combobox has a scroll bar for list items. While selecting list item from the wpfcombobox using `SelectedIndex` we get this error:

> Result StackTrace:
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.Engine.IScreenElement.SetValueAsComboBox(String bstrNewValue, Int32 nSetValueAsComboBoxFlag)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.SetValueAsComboBoxInternal(String value, SetValueAsComboBoxType setValueAsComboBoxType)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.SetValueAsComboBoxUsingQueryId(String value)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.TechnologyElementPropertyProvider.SetValueUsingQueryId(UITestControl uiControl, Int32[] selectedIndices, String technologyName, Int32 maxCount)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.WpfComboBoxPropertyProvider.SetPropertyValue(UITestControl uiTestControl, String propertyName, Object value)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UiaPropertyProvider.SetPropertyValue(UITestControl uiTestControl, String propertyName, Object value)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestPropertyProvider.SetPropertyValueWrapper(UITestControl uiControl, String propertyName, Object value)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.SetPropertyValue(String propertyName, Object propertyValue)
>        --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>           at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowComException(COMException innerException, IPlaybackContext context)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(Exception exception, IPlaybackContext context)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(Exception exception, String actionName, UITestControl uiControl)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(Exception exception, String actionName, Object parameterValue, UITestControl uiControl)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.SetPropertyValue(String propertyName, Object propertyValue)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.SetPropertyPrivate(String propertyName, Object value)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.<>c__DisplayClass180_0.b__0()
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod[T](Func`1 function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent, Boolean logAsAction)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.SetProperty(String propertyName, Object value)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.WpfControls.WpfComboBox.set_SelectedIndex(Int32 value)
>          at MC2.Tests.CUIT.Handwritten.UnitConversion.Unit_Conversion.UnitConverterLargeUnits() in D:\VSTS2015\MC2Main\MC2.Tests.CUIT.Handwritten\Unit Conversion\UnitConversion.cs:line 333
>       Result Message: 
>       Test method MC2.Tests.CUIT.Handwritten.UnitConversion.Unit_Conversion.UnitConverterLargeUnits threw exception: 
>       Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.PlaybackFailureException: Cannot perform 'SetProperty of SelectedIndex with value "0"' on the control. Additional Details: 
>       TechnologyName:  'UIA'
>       FrameworkId:  'WPF'
>       ControlType:  'ComboBox'
>       AutomationId:  'UnitConverterViewModel_ToUnit_comboBox'
>        ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0xF004F006

Code for list item selection is as below:

```
DataTable dt = commonfunc.getExcelDataUsingConnection(excelConn, sheetname);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   fromunit = row["FromUnit"].ToString();
   tounit = row["ToUnit"].ToString();
   tounitexpvalue = row["ExpectedValue"].ToString();
   fromunitname = row["InputUnit"].ToString();
   tounitname = row["OutputUnit"].ToString();

   WpfComboBox funit = new WpfComboBox();

   funit = commonfunc.GetCUITCombobox(parent, "automationID",     "UnitConverterViewModel_FromUnit_comboBox", 0);

   Mouse.Click(funit);
}

for (int test = 0; test < funit.Items.Count; test++)
{

     string txt = funit.Items[test].GetChildren()[0].FriendlyName;

        if (txt.ToLower().Trim() == fromunitname.ToLower().Trim())
           {
                funit.SelectedIndex = test;
                break;
           }

}

WpfListItem fromUnitItem = new WpfListItem();
fromUnitItem = commonfunc.GetCUITListItem(funit, "automationId", fromunit, 0);
funit.Expanded = true;
Mouse.Click(fromUnitItem);
```